# Functions, File handling

Tags: python

I made this code, but when I try to append, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 9,in main
    elif what == 'a': append(thisFile)
  File "main.py", line 27, in append
    for record in range(5):file.write("New "+str(record)+"\n") and file.close()
ValueError: I/O operationon closed file.

```

When I try to create or read a file it turns out fine, it's just when I append (or add, as the code says). What's wrong?

```
def main():
    print("Simple text files in Python")
    thisFile = input('file name?: ')
    q = 0
    while q != 1:
      q = 1
      what = input('What do you want to do? (create, add, display): ')[:1]
      if what == 'c': create(thisFile)
      elif what == 'a': append(thisFile)
      elif what == 'd': read(thisFile)
      else: 
        print('Invalid choice, pick another: ')      
        q = 0

def create(filename):
    print("Creating file ...")
    file=open(filename,"w")
    i = 'y'
    while i == 'y':
        file.write(input('what do you want to write?') + '\n')
        i = input('one more line?(y/n): ').lower()
    file.close()

def append(filename):
    print("Adding to file ...")
    file=open(filename,"a")
    for record in range(5):file.write("New "+str(record)+"\n") and file.close()

def read(filename):
    print("Reading file ...")
    file=open(filename,"r")
    for record in file:
        text=record
        print(text)
    file.close()
do = 'y'
while do == 'y':
  main()
  do = input('Any other functions?:(y/n): ')
```

Comment: You explicitly close the file after the first line. Why don't you put it outside the loop, as you have elsewhere?

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks.. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Alternatively, use the "context manager" `with open...`, which automatically closes the file when the nested block ends.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @jonrsharpe as a comment, the problem is you explicity close the file in the statement below:

```
for record in range(5):file.write("New "+str(record)+"\n") and file.close()
```

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

> "f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning
>   the number of characters written."

So when you are writing to the file it's returning a number different of zero, which is used as "**True**" value by the "**and**" operator. Because the first value is "True", the second expression "**file.close()**" is evaluated and the file is closed. So on the next iteration it tries to write to a file that is no longer opened and you receive the error.